# Mounting a disk image without the "nodev" option

Tags: terminal, mount

I need to mount a disk image. From terminal, I issued:

```
hdiutil attach <myImage.sparseimage>
```

Now if I run `mount` I get:

```
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/<myDisk> (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners, mounted by administrator)
```

The `nodev` flag is creating problems for my next commands. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily change the way `hdiutil` mounts the image. You can, however, change the status of a mounted volume using the `mount` command with the `-u`option. The following will do what you wish:

`sudo mount -u -o dev /Volumes/<mydisk>`

Comment: I didn't try but I think this answers my question. However, after discussions on #macosx @freenode, I found out that creating and accessing device nodes on a mounted volume could create serious problems to my whole system (they explained that a new node on the mounted volume could wrongly reference my hdd, so a program wishing to write to that node could actually write to my hdd and corrupt it). Do you agree with this?

Comment: Yep, adding and accessing device nodes directly is dangerous and can be fraught with problems.